# Highcharts X-Axis as Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/Lq6me/), with out changing the series data, Is it possible to show x-axis labels as text i.e. {"apple","orange","mango"} instead of decimals i.e{0,1,2} with out seperating labels from JSON and providing it to Categories.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
            xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            enabled: true
            }
    },

    series:  [{name:"ser1",data:[["apple",29.9], ["orange",71.5], ["mango",106.4]]},{name:"ser2",data:[["apple",40], ["mango",90]]}]        
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use catgories in xAxis

```
categories: ["apple","orange","mango"],
```

I've updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Lq6me/1/

if don't want to use categories you can go for

```
labels:{
formatter: function() {}
}
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(function () {
var seriesData = [{name:"ser1",data:[["apple",29.9], ["orange",71.5], ["mango",106.4]]},{name:"ser2",data:[["apple",40], ["mango",90]]}];

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
            xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() { return seriesData[0].data[this.value][0];},
            }
    },
    series:  seriesData     
  });
});
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M2sBS/)

Comment: thanks.. updated http://jsfiddle.net/M2sBS/.. i think there is no way to get this done with out taking help of categories..